# Why is this string to integer conversion function off by 1?

Tags: c++, string

I have written this function that converts a string to an integer. But there seems to be an error which i cant figure out. When i compile my output is 645.

```
int s2i(string s){
   int index_limit = s.length() -1;
   return s2i(s, index_limit, 0,0);
}

int s2i(string s, int index_limit, int sum, int index){
   if(index == s.length()) return sum;
   int value = static_cast<int>( s[index] - '0');
   sum += value * pow(10,index_limit);

   return s2i(s, --index_limit, sum, ++index);
}

int main(){
   string s = "646";
   int val = s2i(s);
   cout << val;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Check it out: http://ideone.com/1VSToh

Comment: After fixing your incomplete code, your code works fine for me. What is the actual problem you observe? Can you reproduce it with the actual code you have posted in this question?

Comment: for me the output is 645

Comment: greg what did u exactly fix?

Comment: I added two required header files, added `using namespace std;` and swapped the declaration order of your `s2i` functions to avoid requiring a forward declaration.

Comment: I could not see any issues other than incomplete code. Which compiler are you using? If you are practicing this is fine, otherwise it is better to use some existing library. May be atoi,atol, strtol etc. you may use. Also check this http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/examples.html#boost_lexical_cast.examples.strings_to_numbers_conversion

Comment: im using GNU GCC compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely losing some accuracy in the call to `pow`. Instead of `pow`, use an integer multiplier.

```
int s2i(string s, int index, int sum, int mult){
   if(index < 0) return sum;
   int value = static_cast<int>( s[index] - '0');
   sum += value * mult;

   return s2i(s, --index, sum, mult*10);
}

int s2i(string s){
   int index_limit = s.length() -1;
   return s2i(s, index_limit, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: great that fixed it. but why am i losing accuracy ?

Comment: @wazeeer, that's the risk of using floating point calculations. Not all floating point numbers can be represented exactly.

Comment: @wazeeer, BTW, my initial post had a logic error that was not apparent when tested with `"646"` but was apparent when tested with `"648"`.

Comment: @wazeeer, the inputs to `pow` are converted to floating point numbers and the return value of `pow` is a floating point number.

Comment: If the call to `pow` was followed by the appropriate "round" it would be OK.